# Setting up a virtual server group with a bridged interface

Tags: virtual-machine, bridge

I posted a specific problem with DHCP over virtual network components [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/1054072/dhcpoffer-not-crossing-virtual-bridge-on-linux), but it is quite specific and does not cover the larger problem I would like to address.

I have a physical server and want to run a collection of VMs on it. The broad structure is

```
**HOST**
(phys interface A ) 
   -- (FW vm A) 
      -- (Some VMs) 
        -- (FW VM B) 
          -- (some more VMs) 
          -- physical interface 
**/HOST**
            -- (physical network)
```

I want `(some more VMs)` to be accessible from `(physical network)` and I want them to be able to provide and/or talk to DHCP server to themselves and to the physical network.

I can create a newtwork from `(FW vm A)` to `(some more VMs)` without any trouble at all ( a bunch of paired VETH devices and bridged cover it.

My problem is getting Linux to actually bridge the physical interface to the VMs. Several issues arise:

- DHCP requests do not not want to cross between physical NIC.
- `ping` requests get duplicated.

I have searched for a description of how to do this, with little luck: many articles speak in broad terms about achieving one of the other, but not both.

What I would really appreciate is a 'best practice' guide, if such exists. The key problem that stymies my attempts is that "bridged networking" provided by VirtualBox and VMWare does not seem to work on Linux (VMs with "bridged" interfaces copied from Windows do not work on Linux).

**Edit: See comments for solution as suggested by @dirkt** -- it was a hardware/driver problem with the network card. It all works well with a different physical NIC. Th faulty card/driver was an Intel 225-V (Gen 2).

Comment: The key here is which kind of VMs you use. Both VirtualBox and VMWare have their own nomenclature (and a different one each, and "bridged" doesn't always mean what I think it would mean in that context). If you use some kind of containers that involve a network namespace, you can just use a macvlan.

Comment: I attempted to use macvlan, but DHCP packets refused to cross it in one direction...a DHCP request was sent out from the virtual server, made it to the physical server on the real network, a DHCPOFFER was sent back by the DHCPD, but never made it past the hosts NIC. That is more or less what is described in my other post here (https://serverfault.com/questions/1054072/dhcpoffer-not-crossing-virtual-bridge-on-linux), with tcpdump output. I just assumed I was doing something wrong in terms of best practice.

Comment: DHCP from macvlans in network namespaces works fine for me. Possibly some bug in your NIC driver? Can you try on different hardware?

Comment: Just checking what "DHCP from macvlans in network namespaces" means...I have not explicitly set up a namespace, and the DHCP server in my test was a separate machine, on the real network. DHCP within the macvlan works fine. Someone suggested turning on hairpin, but that only applies to actual bridges AFAICT. Is there a way to see what's happening to the DHCPOFFER? It just seems to disappear...

FWIW, there were three commands used to set up the macvlan, but the main one was ```ip link add mvlan_bn_bld2 link eth_int type macvlan mode bridge```.

Comment: I am using an "Intel Corporation Device 15f3 (rev 02)" NIC, and will try a "Intel Corporation I350 Gigabit Network Connection (rev 01)" instead.

Comment: @dirkt It looks like you were completely correct. The 2.5GBit Ethernet on the motherboard does not seem to work, but the 1GB dual port card, does. What's more, the VirtualBox "bridged" mode works as well.

What can I do to diagnose the cause? Might it be a setting issue for the card? I'm very happed to dump extra info into the original post if it can be useful in diagnosing this!!

Comment: File a bug report on the kernel development list. First see if they have some specific list for that driver. Do mention that it works with different hardware. This is not an issue we can figure out here.